# D3.js - Multiple selections within a zoomable sunburst

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm quite new to using D3.js and I'm currently working on customising a zoomable sunburst based upon the Coffee Flavour Wheel. [Here's an example](https://www.jasondavies.com/coffee-wheel/).

I am looking to have multiple selections of the top level data selected before clicking a link to zooming in one level which filters the data.

Is there a way of filtering the data on the click event? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm having a hard time trying to understand what your problem is. A code snipper would help

Comment: I think my initial question was edited - I am looking to have multiple selections before zooming into the next level and filtering the data based upon those selections. I may need to add a jsfiddle if still not clear.